# Getting HDD no in php or C

Tags: php, c

Hay All

Can we get the hard-disk number using php or C 
Is there possible or not ?

This is not a problem just configuring.

Comment: What does "hard-disk no" mean?

Comment: like the hdd serial number? try running in a linux console `hdparm -i /dev/sda` as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using linux just read the file, /etc/fstab

I'm looking around for a windows equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You may try querying for the "Win32_logicalDisk" WMI instances under root/cimV2. This will list all the available logical Volumes in the system. 
Maybe considered an equivalent to the linux /etc/fstab, you'll also get additional info about the logical volumes like, their Drive letter, Serial Number, block size, total blocks and so on